# Class size paradox vs. length-biased sampling

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling, paradoxes

According to Introduction To Probability by Blitzenstein and Hwang p. 244, one example of length-biased sampling is the following:

"For example, asking randomly chosen mothers how many children they have yields a different distribution from asking randomly chosen people how many siblings they have, including themselves."

This seems like an instance of the class-size paradox. How is this also an example of length-biased sampling given the definition from Wikipedia

"Length bias is an overestimation of survival duration due to the relative excess of cases detected that are asymptomatically slowly progressing, while fast progressing cases are detected after giving symptoms."

I'm not really seeing the connection.

Comment: Suppose family $A$ has two parents and 20 children and family $B$ has two parents and $1$ child.  If you choose from *parents* randomly... or choose from *children* randomly....   Ummm... don't you see how the results will differ?

Comment: I agree.  It's certainly an instance of the class-size paradox.  I'm not familiar with length-biased sampling, but the family-size example doesn't fit the Wikipedia definition at all.

Comment: @saulspatz: I have seen a more general definition: *length bias occurs when the sampling scheme implies that the probability of observing a positive‐valued random variable is proportional to the value of the variable*.

Comment: That more general definition makes sense to explain why this is an example of length bias -- thanks @BrianM.Scott !